# Sorting ruby array as alphanumeric

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array in Ruby by length and alphanumeric:

The desired order would be:

- site.com?page=7
- site.com?page=8
- site.com?page=9
- site.com?page=880

I've been trying array.sort and sort! but none of them seems to do the trick, as they will place the 880 next after 8.

How would I go about doing this the most effective way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say you have an array:

```
a = ["site.com?page=7", "site.com?page=8", "site.com?page=9", "site.com?page=880"]
```

Then you can do:

```
a = a.sort_by{|t| t.split(/page=/)[1].to_i}
```

In short I use a custom sort criteria and that criteria is to split the string by "page=", then use the numerical value(`to_i`) of the string after the first match of `page=` for the sorting.

Comment: Thanks. Though I'm afraid I should have posted the entire URI, as page is just one of many. Is it still possible to do something?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `group_by` function to group items by length and `sort_by` to order them alphanumerically within the group, and finally flatten the groups:

```
list.group_by {|i| i.length}.sort_by{|i| i.first}.collect {|i| i.last.sort}.flatten
```

Answer (score 0):

A general trick is to zero pad the numbers using a fixed number of decimal places before sorting the array strings.

This can be easily accomplished by the following code:

```
a = ["site.com?page=9","site.com?page=880""site.com?page=8","site.com?page=7"]

N = 5  # Maximum number of decimal places allowed

a.sort_by { |s| s.gsub(/(\d+)/) { |n| sprintf("%0#{N}d", n.to_i) } }
```

This works well unless the strings contain any number greater than or equal to 10^N.